# Needing to pan screen for graphics to update in ArcMap?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, layers, display, arcgis-10.6

Every time I add or change a layer or zoom in/out, I need to use the pan tool to move the  screen a little bit before the screen updates.

Is there a setting that should be changed to fix this?

I am running ArcMap 10.6 on a brand new computer with some pretty beefy hardware, so I don't think it's due to an equipment limitation.

Comment: Have you installed any 3rd party add-ins, extensions, etc?

Comment: No, only things directly from Esri.

Comment: Try updating your graphic drivers?

Comment: Updating graphic drivers seemed to work for a little while, but today I'm having the same problem.

Comment: UPDATE: It seems that everything works fine until I add a basemap, and then the problem comes back. Changing the projection of the layers and data frame doesn't have any effect.

Comment: I'm having the same problem. The same issue occurs on map scale resolution change. If I change it from say, 1:100,000 to 1:500,000 nothing happens. I can't pan, the screen does not redraw. The zoom tool fails to work and then I pan it freezes and then Arc crashes. New computer I7 processor, 32GB ram, no other software etc. QGIS works fine. This is an ArcGIS 10.6 issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on a "beefy" computer. It turns out that it's probably too beefy. It's likely an issue with the beefy graphics card. When you run ArcMap right click and run the program with your integrated graphics card.

My posted issue on ESRI's Community page:
https://community.esri.com/thread/227151-arcmap-103-stops-refreshing-map-image-after-action